# How to setup a cron job in SQLyog

Tags: cron, cron-task, sqlyog

I want to create a scheduled job in SQLyog (or suggest me if any) that will run a SQL query every 30 minutes.

I want to run the query -

```
UPDATE `db`.`table` SET sessiontime = CEILING(sessiontime/6)*6 WHERE id>1000
```

Please help me to figure out this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/) is a windows tool for managing MySQL databases. Windows usually don't have a cron, instead it has the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569).

SQLyog has something build in which is called the Job Agent, which allows you to execute queries and generate, format and send personalized mails with results. These jobs are saved as XML files, which can be executed with SQLyog. This is used to use the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) for performing regular querying (as a matter of fact, you can either put them there if you want to or use SQLyog to do this for you).

Basically, use the wizard to put in all the data required (database connection, smtp options, query), test it, then use the Job Agent to put this into the Windows Task Scheduler.

Keep in mind, the feature Job Agent is available in SQLyog Enterprise and Ultimate only. The free edition doesn't have it unlocked.

Comment: Hi Bjoern, Thanks for your answer. I just want to schedule my queries that should be performed in every 30 minutes. Is there any other program/software that may be helpful. I don't have the enterprise edition of SQLyog and don't want to buy this if its not easy to schedule a task. I saw something named "SQL Event Scheduler" . Do you know how can I use that? or recommend me any other software if possible please.

Comment: What OS are you using? Windows? Is the database local or remote?